# Which Eclipse version should I use for an Android application ? Eclipse Scout OR Ecplise JEE?

Tags: eclipse

I am I'm going to run an Android project with Eclipse, Which Eclipse version should I use for an Android application ? Eclipse Scout OR Eclipse JEE ??
Can I use Android code with Eclipse JEE ?

Answer (score 0):

Is there a special reason why you want to use some of the mentioned IDEs? I would suggest using Android Studio. I am using that and I am happy with that. If you want to stay with Eclipse, use Eclipse Che or even Eclipse EE with Android SDK if you like.

Or what are your special requirements?

Comment: Thank you for your answer  , Do you have any education for Android programming using Java ? As regards I'm a bit Java programmer and I worked with Eclipse so far and I have a new project that must to be written for Android and iOS , so I have to switch to Android programming , I'm confused with Android Studio , please help me . Thank